# How to fix: "The editor has encountered an unexpected error"?

Tags: block-editor

I have disabled all plugins and I'm still getting this error.
It is preventing users from creating a post.

The error is:

> The editor has encountered an unexpected error.

What is the fix for this?

Comment: please check error in console and debug on in wp-config.php file

Comment: `TypeError: "e.visibility is undefined"` - `react-dom.min.js:104:245`

Comment: The best solution I have so far is to disable the abomination of a mess that the react JS based Gutenberg is with [disable gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/)

Comment: Don't disable it. Here is the solution: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/325113/the-editor-has-encountered-an-unexpected-error-typeerror-cannot-read-proper/

Comment: Most of the time "Yoast SEO" is the main cause

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try to configure Nginx as below?

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

From https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12655

I encountered this error. After I correct my Nginx config, it works very well.