# The editor has encountered an unexpected error. // TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of null

Tags: custom-post-types, errors, block-editor

when I tried to edit a post of a custom post type, I experienced this error.

[image]

When I press "Copy Error" I am getting this:

```php
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prefix' of null
    at https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/edit-post.min.js?ver=3.1.6:12:56693
    at ph (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:97:88)
    at eg (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:125:307)
    at fg (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:126:168)
    at wc (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:138:237)
    at fa (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:137:115)
    at gg (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:135:196)
    at Ca (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:133:365)
    at Object.enqueueSetState (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.6.3:191:324)
    at r.q.setState (https://example.com/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=16.6.3:20:304)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,
I was researching this topic a bit deeper. All answers found on this SE suggested disabling Gutenberg with a plugin. This couldn't be a valid "fix" in my oppinion.

After researching and browsing through the git issues of `WordPress/gutenberg` I've found a pretty easy solution for this problem.

The user `joshuafredrickson` on the git suggested changing the args of the custom post type array from `'public' => false,` to **true**.

I have checked that fix on multiple of my clients projects and it has worked every single time.

**Credits:**

- https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/12482#issuecomment-445022253

Comment: How do you do this from the wordpress admin?

Comment: @StevieG Edit the file that includes the custom post-type

Answer (score 0):

Now in 2022, this was solved by changing `'show_in_rest' => true` to `'show_in_rest' => false`. My `public` option was already set to true. I thought I needed `show_in_rest` to be set to true for some reason, but turning it off doesn't seem to be affecting my site at all. We'll see...

Comment: Can you please point to the filename and line number where I've got to change this?

Comment: I changed it in my custom post type code in the `register_post_type()` args. You would not have the same filename and line number since I added the post type in a custom plugin.